# ORDER BY ou LIMIT. O que é processado primeiro no Select do SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, order-by, select-limit

Amigos, o que é processado primeiro no Select do SQL? O "Order by" ou o "Limit"?

Por exemplo, se tenho uma tabela com cidades de vários estados. Então busco as cidades com mais de 100 mil habitantes do estado X, resultando em 6 cidades (ex: cidades listadas sem usar order by: Gama, Alfa, Zeta, Teta, Delta e Beta) .

Então mudo o sql e ordeno por Nome ASC e limito em 4 cidades (Limit 4).

Como Select vai proceder? Ele vai primeiro ordenar as 6 cidades (todo o resultado) em ordem alfabética ascendente e limitar as 4 primeiras (resultado: Alfa, Beta, Delta e Gama)? Ou vai primeiro limitar 4 cidades da busca (primeiro ele limita o resultado) e então ordenar elas em ordem alfabética (resultado: Alfa, Gama, Teta e Zeta)?

A quantidade de registros da tabela (se forem muitos) pode influenciar no procedimento do Select de limitar primeiro ou ordenar primeiro?

Estou usando BD MySql, não sei se faz alguma diferença neste caso.

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda!

Ps: nos testes que eu fiz com poucos registros, ele ordenou primeiro e só então limitou, mas queria ter certeza se é este mesmo procedimento sempre, independente de número de registros na tabela ou de alguma outra variável que eu desconheça.

Comment: sim, ordena primeiro e limita depois, independentemente do numero de registos da tabela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder ordenar e limitar, o SELECT vai precisar primeiro saber todos os registros, para então ordená-los e, só após isso, aplicar o LIMIT. Seria impossível aplicar um LIMIT com ORDER BY sem antes ter o SELECT completo para ser ordenado.